# D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx Access Violation (nvd3dum.dll)

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I am trying to create a game and I need sprites so I have built a small image class that creates a texture from a file but something really weird is happening.

Sometimes it works (like 80% of the times) but sometimes it crashes with the following error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6BFC2B06 (nvd3dum.dll) in Application.exe: 
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.
```

I do not think that there is a bug in the nVidia drivers but rather in my code.

I am not 100% sure that the problem lays within my Image class but when I do not create any Images it does not crash .

I have no idea how to pinpoint the exact location of the error, is there something wrong with my Image class or should I look elsewhere.

CImage.h:

```
class CImage {
public:
    CImage(COverlay* overlay, const char* fileName, int w, int h);

    void draw(float x, float y, Color c = Color::White());

    int getWidth();
    int getHeight();

private:
    COverlay* _overlay;
    const char* _fileName;

    int _w;
    int _h;

    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 _texture;
    LPD3DXSPRITE _sprite;
};
```

CImage.cpp:

```
CImage::CImage(COverlay* overlay, const char* fileName, int w, int h) {
    _overlay = overlay;
    _fileName = fileName;
    _w = w;
    _h = h;

    int eCode;
    if (FAILED(eCode = D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(overlay->GetDevice(), fileName, w, h, D3DX_DEFAULT, NULL, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0xFFFF00FF, NULL, NULL, &_texture))) {
        std::string error_msg = "There was an error creating the texture for an image. Make sure the file is available. Requested file: ";
        error_msg += fileName;
        error_msg += ", Error: ";
        switch (eCode) {
        case D3DERR_INVALIDCALL:
            error_msg += "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL";
            break;
        case D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE:
            error_msg += "D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE";
            break;
        case D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY:
            error_msg += "D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY";
            break;
        case D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA:
            error_msg += "D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA";
            break;
        case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
            error_msg += "E_OUTOFMEMORY";
            break;
        }
        error_msg += ".";
        MessageBox(NULL, error_msg.c_str(), "Error", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (FAILED(D3DXCreateSprite(overlay->GetDevice(), &_sprite))) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "There was an error creating a DirectX sprite.", "Error", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }
}

void CImage::draw(float x, float y, Color c) {
    if (_texture && _sprite) {
        _sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

        D3DXVECTOR3 pos = { x, y, 0 };
        _sprite->Draw(_texture, NULL, NULL, &pos, c.Code());

        _sprite->End();
    }
}

int CImage::getWidth() {
    return _w;
}

int CImage::getHeight() {
    return _h;
}
```

Code to create the images (when this is commented out the application does not crash):

```
    CMenuBox::_boxHeader = new CImage("../plaatjes/box_header.png", 152, 40);
    CMenuBox::_boxPattern = new CImage("../plaatjes/box_pattern.png", 152, 1);
    CMenuBox::_boxBottom = new CImage("../plaatjes/box_bottom.png", 152, 16); 
    CMenuBox::_boxDivider = new CImage("../plaatjes/divider.png", 134, 2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Run the program in the debugger.  When or if it crashes, you will know the line of code that caused the issue by inspecting the call stack.  Regardless, when you write code like this, you should familiarize yourself with the debugger and how to use it appropriately.

Comment: Some of the parameters you passed into D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx() are not correct, you should read the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hmmm.. `new CImage("../plaatjes/box_header.png", 152, 40);`  3 parameters.  `CImage(COverlay* overlay, const char* fileName, int w, int h);` 4 parameters.  Something isn't adding up here.  Your constructor has 4 params, but you're creating instances of `CImage` with 3 parameters.

Comment: I actually use a wrapper for the initialization but I quickly removed it here.

I use a debugger, it can't tell a line because it happens in external code.

Comment: @J.vanDijk When the crash occurs, look at the **call stack** to see which call *your* program made that led to the error.

Comment: I can't read the call stack as everything in it is external code.

Comment: BTW, you should consider using DirectX 11 and the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) instead, particularly the ``DDSTextureLoader`` module and ``SpriteBatch`` class. All versions of D3DX are deprecated, as is the [legacy DIrectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) itself and Direct3D 9 for that matter.